# enabling bucket logging using boto3

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3

I have a list of bucket names that I need to enable logging on programmatically. I am using boto3 and lambda. I can't seem to find the correct function in boto3/s3 to do what I need although I'm sure it's possible. Here is my code so far:

```
import json
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement

    # print("hanlder:event")
    # print(event)
    # bucketDump()
    setBucketPolicy(bucketDump())


def bucketDump():
    ##This program lists all exsisting buckets within an aws account (Tommy's Personal Account)
    response = s3.list_buckets()

    buckets = []
    for bucket in response['Buckets']:
            value = bucket["Name"]
            buckets.append(value)
    return buckets

##setting a bucket policy
def setBucketPolicy(buckets):
    for bucket in buckets:
        value = s3.get_bucket_logging(bucket)
        print(value)


        ##TODO if bucket in buckets does not have loggin enabled, enable it!

        # print(bucket)
```

My process is I want to iterate over the list of buckets I have and enable_logging for them! Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#bucketlogging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @jordanm in the comment below your question, using a resource instead of the client would make your life much easier as it provides a higher-level interface.

If the only goal of the `bucketDump` in your question was to retrieve all the buckets in your account, then you could totally remove it and use the standard function `s3.buckets.all()` that already returns an iterable of buckets ([docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.ServiceResource.buckets)).

Assuming that you want to enable logging on all your buckets that don't have it already enabled **and** that you want to deliver logs from all the buckets to the same bucket, you could add a parameter to the `` function to specify this bucket. The implementation suggested below will enable logging and result in logs being organized like so:

```yml
- name_of_bucket_in_wich_to_store_logs
  - bucket_name_1
    - logs
  - bucket_name_2
    - logs
```

If you want to organize your logs differently you have to play with the `TargetBucket` and `TargetPrefix` parameters and, if needed, you can specify other parameters for grants as detailed in the [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.BucketLogging.put).

```py
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    setBucketPolicy(target_bucket='name_of_bucket_in_wich_to_store_logs')


def setBucketPolicy(target_bucket: str):
    for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
        bucket_logging = s3.BucketLogging(bucket.name)
        if not bucket_logging.logging_enabled:
            bucket_logging.put(
                BucketLoggingStatus={
                    'LoggingEnabled': {
                        'TargetBucket': target_bucket,
                        'TargetPrefix': f'{bucket.name}/'
                    }
                }
            )
```